What does an intersection between two universes look like?
In this scenario, two universes intersect. During the intersection, they do not bounce off of each other. Instead, they pass through each other and intersect. What would the intersection look like? Here is what I've found so far:
Two non-parallel lines (1D) intersect each other at a point.
Two planes (2D) intersect each other along a line.
Two 3D universes would (from my extrapolation) intersect along a two-dimensional sheet which divides each universe into "in front" and "behind" the intersection relative to an observer. However, I am not sure if it's true and how directions will be perceived when looking at the intersection area.
For start, I don't know how an observer would perceive any change in the intersection angle. Second, two intersecting universes must exist in a one higher dimension. For instance, two intersecting lines (1D) are drawn on a 2D paper. Two intersecting planes (2D) must be floated in the known 3D space, and therefore two 3D universes must be floated in a 4D coordinate system. Since we cannot perceive the fourth spacial dimension, how would I be able to see what's in the other universe if we stand at the intersection plane?

Do they have the same rules/universal constants and fields?  Otherwise, it's going to be a lot wilder than just mere geometry.

This is true - if the quantum constants (i.e. Planck constant, electron charge, etc) are different, then things are going to get complicated as the quantum physics of both universes start to interact.

Funny, I asked this exact question in the sandbox and eventually abandoned it

Let's admit the truth before I suggest a solution

There is no evidence of the existence of multiple universes.
There is no evidence of the existence of a fourth physical dimension.

In other words, what the collision looks like to human eyes is a hypothetical mathematical speculation at best (hypothetical questions are prohibited by the Help Center) and at worst it's a silly wild-@$! guess.
Which makes this question either closable as opinion-based or a question of the purest worldbuilding ethic: we don't and can't know what it looks like so let's set some rules! I'm favoring the latter. A bit unusual for me, but the question might have a basis that would make sense in a story.
My Answer
What would humanity see? The problem is exemplified by asserting that two 2D objects intersect in a 3D context. We live in a 3D context, so that should be something we can see, right?
Wrong. 2D means infinitely thin in the third axis. Their intersection would create an infinitely thin line. Unless we define a rule such as the release of energy in the 3D plane due to the 2D object collision, there's no way to see an infinitely thin line. Walking through it wouldn't cut us in half. We'd not even notice it was there.
Likewise, two 3D objects colliding on a 4D plane would also not be noticeable for the same reasons. We couldn't "see" the intersection of the universes.
Let's start with energy...
But then there's that rule... Worldbuilding isn't about how to crowbar the impossible into known science! As Arthur C. Clarke once said, "The only way of discovering the limits of the possible is to venture a little way past them into the impossible." That's what we're doing!
Worldbuilding Rule: Either gravity or energy (or both) transcend dimensions.
This isn't as unreasonable as it may seem. Borrowing loosely from a question on Physics.se, photons have no dimension. It appears, therefore, that they exist on all three dimensional planes: 1D, 2D and 3D — and yet they can be detected!. A fair assumption is that, if a 4D plane exists, they would exist there, too.
The fact that we don't see glowing, ghostly lines all over the place where two 2D objects are colliding can suggest either (a) our worldbuilding rule has no basis in fact despite using photons as an example or (b) there is no such thing as 2D objects, which could suggest there's no such thing as 4D space, too. But that's all boring!
So, what humanity could see are the reflected images... the light... of objects not in our 3D space that are passing through our 3D space in a 4D context. We could see the planet, but there'd be nothing to land on. The physicality of the other universe remains entirely intact.
The fun thing about this is that if we simplify our understanding of science, there's nothing to suggest this isn't actually happening. Who's to say that some galaxy we're observing isn't really there and it's only light? Hah! This is fun!
Now let's think about gravity
This complicates things. If I recall correctly, a "gravity wave" or string or whatever is a zero-dimensional object, too. Thus, like photons, we could conclude that they exist on all physical planes.
Which is why that star we think actually exists might be another universe passing through ours! Even gravitational lensing would work.
But there's a problem with gravity: a universe has a lot of gravity. Granted, it's kinda spread out... but what happens in a collision? Two universes passing through one another would screw each other up something awful. It's making my eyes bleed just thinking about it. What a human could see is almost irrelevant as the passage of the two universes could, theoretically, throw the contents of each universe willy-nilly all over the place. Now my ears are bleeding.
Conclusion
I'm favoring the idea that since photons appear to be dimensionless (I'm sure an actual physicist reading this is going into apoplectic shock and about to write a doctrinal thesis rebutting this, but let's roll with it), the passage of the two universes can be seen — but not touched.

To ease your concerns about physicist’s opinions on your ideas, photons are indeed dimensionless. Their wave functions may occupy a nonzero volume of space, but the wave function tells where the photon is likely to be and is independent of its actual physical shape - the photon itself is a point-like particle that happens to have uncertain position.

Physicist Brian Greene gave a traveling lecture a few years back about what we would see if the Big Bang of another universe occurred within our universe. I cannot find that presentation online, but you might try looking through his speeches/writings.

This is one of the coolest what ifs I have ever read. Distant galaxies being an entirely different universe is dope

Do you mean "no evidence of a fourth spatial dimension"?  Because under GR and even just SR, Time is definitely a physical dimension.  And the Standard Model does too (as it incorporate SR as well)

If the "echo" of the other universe interacting with ours is gravity, we could "feel it" by bubbles of gravitational force coming from apparently empty spaces, somewhat like Dark Matter

@RBarryYoung Yes. I didn't think it needed to be explicitly stated due to my use of the 2D example. Keep in mind that on this Stack people have played around with a fourth (and more) spatial dimension a lot. The arbitrary "spacetime" assignment of time as the fourth dimension is an Einsteinian truth, but it's not an obvious solution, which is why it's usually shorthanded as 3+1 (3 spatial 1 temporal) vs. 4+0 (4 spatial no temporal). But, that's for physicists to worry about.

@Mermaker That crossed my mind! But I didn't have time to chase it when I wrote this answer, and so didn't include it. That would make for a hilarious story: the entire theory of dark matter being nothing more than an erroneous mathematical model based on our misunderstanding of what happens when two 3D universes collide in a 4D context. Love the idea!

Were a true four-dimensional object to be embedded in our 3-spatial-dimension universe (i.e. the intersection brane between our universe and another, both of which are embedded in a 4-spatial-dimension superspace), we as humans would only be able to perceive a 3-dimensional cross section of it.
For example, consider the Calabi-Yau manifold. The quintic manifold is actually six-dimensional, but even as weak three-dimensional humans we can perceive a given two-dimensional cross-section of it; citation: the image on the wikipedia article.
The intersection point would probably look something like that: a constantly-shifting surface curving back in on itself at several locations. As the universes slide past each other, the intersection brane changes as well, which leads to the constant changing of the 3D section of the brane. What it would look like visually depends on what kind of light it emits - it might look like a gravitational lens and nothing else, or a blindingly-bright white hole. Those specifics are up to you as the person who is intersecting universes.


Lastly, you are misunderstanding the term “Universe”. That Uni- prefix means “Everything”. As we are inside our universe, everything we can see, measure, and detect, even those things we cannot detect, but are still there, exists INSIDE our universe. The fact that we could detect the other universes means that they are NOT parallel universes, but are in-fact also part of our universe!

Source: quora This means for me, that the universes would merge.
This answer for an other question states:

In the Quilted Multiverse proposal, all of the universes share the same spacetime: they are just a long way apart in space and “intersection” has no meaning. In the Quantum Multiverse proposal (a version of the Many Worlds interpretation of quantum theory), the universes again share the same spacetime, which itself branches into separate universes. In the Inflationary Multiverse proposal, when a universe is spawned as a “bubble” universe in the inflationary spacetime, the time dimension in the bubble universe is, in a way, disconnected from that in the host spacetime: the intersection is at the boundary of the bubble, which to observers inside the bubble universe appears as “time zero” (i.e. the Big Bang).


Its a source of "lawlessness". As in you have your physics following your models seems to life within laws and even the "unexplained" part behaving within the scope of the current standard model.
Now your universes intersect each other at a spot - lets call it a gate in the following aspects:

scale : Universes may be very different in size depending on frame of reference. The fields of the empty space noise may be enough, to significantly push around galaxies in a "smaller" universe beyond the gate.

generalized universe parameters: Gravity, weak interaction, strong interaction, electromagnetic forces - they may all be slightly off. As a result of this for example one universe may be filled with anti-matter.

gateshadow: Depending on the gates nature, it may cause stresses in the universes structure, blowing a "hole"-silouette shadow into the microwave background, because the big-bang shoved the material right through the gate. A gate into a new born universe, may be quite the torch..



One could imagine that the metric gets messed so that in both universes, suddenly half of the universe (which half depends on where you are relative to the intersection plane) gets "replaced" with half of the other universe. As the plane shifts

if the plane is moving towards you, stuff from "your" universe disappears, to be replaced with the stuff from the other universe

if the plane is moving away from you, stuff from "your" universe reappears, the "other" stuff disappears.

one could maybe cross from one side to the other, as long as one is moving very fast relative to the movement of the boundary. Maybe. Photons would always be able to cross because they always move at light speed relative to the observer. No idea what would happen if the boundary moves at / over light speed though. Then you might just see a black horizon.


